# HTML5: Server preventing video files from being accessed

Tags: html

I have .mp4, .ogv and webm (HTML5 video formats) lying on my server in a particular directory.  When I use ftp, I can access and play the videos files, although I do have to pass through a security window. When I try to access the files through the webpage, it wont work. In the webpage I am following the standard way in which html5 video tag is provided with the source of the video file.

The webpage works fine on my local wamp server but not on the online server. Is it something to do with the configuration of the online server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Some hosting companies do not allow all mime-types/extensions. Please contact with your hosting company. There may be an option to add desired extension on your control panel.